# Is it possible to share a promise between to sibling components via the redux store?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have two components, DeleteCards and ConfirmModal. The DeleteCards component shows cards that can be deleted.

When the user clicks `deleteCard` an action updates the state like so:

```
{ showModal : true, title : 'Delete card', body : 'Are you sure?'}
```

So, this now causes my modal window to show up asking the user to confirm. The problem is that I need my deleteCard function to now wait and listen to the confirmation click inside the modal.

I can technically do this:

```
{ showModal : true, title : 'Delete card', body : 'Are you sure?', promise: promiseRef }
```

But, I know this is an anti-pattern. So, what are my options here? Or what would be the redux way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score -1):

Technically that's not a Redux related issue, you could just pass a function as a prop:
`<ConfirmModal onConfirm={this.onModalConfirm}/>`

Or, if you're 100% decided into Redux, just make a flag, kind of, `modalConfirmed`, add it to `mapStateToProps`, in your `componentDidUpdate`, check for that prop, and then control the function you needed.